# Proper way to set the size.z of <heightmap><size></size><heightmap>

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To put things into context I have a DEM stored in a geotiff with proper gdal metadata set, I am using Gazebo9.

Let's say the DEM has max_elevation of 5.0 and and a min_elevation value of 1.0.

How do I correctly set the value of **z_scale** value (shown below) if I want to maintain the same height values stored in the dem?

```
<heightmap><size>desired_width desired_height z_scale</size></heightmap>
```

By examining https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo9/gazebo/physics/HeightmapShape.cc and https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo9/gazebo/rendering/Heightmap.cc gazebo seems to use the following formula `(max_elevation-min_elevation)/max_elevation`, this means that z_scale would be `(5.0-1.0)/5.0=0.8`.

I read somewhere that I should be using the formula `max_elevation-min_elevation` which mean the z_scale value would `5.0-1.0=4.0`. Is this correct?

Also how much reliable is the GDAL metadata parsing code within Gazebo9. Can I just rely on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25600/proper-way-to-set-the-size.z-of-%3Cheightmap%3E%3Csize%3E%3C/size%3E%3Cheightmap%3E/) by [Samahu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25193/samahu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2020-08-07**:\

> how much reliable is the GDAL metadata parsing code within Gazebo9. Can I just rely on that?
> If you explicitly set `<size>`, gazebo will use that, but if not it will infer the size from the DEM file. I haven't done benchmarking on its accuracy or tested for bugs, but I will be happy to investigate any bug reports about it.
> https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo9_9.13.1/gazebo/physics/HeightmapShape.cc#L93-L103

**Comment by [Samahu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25193/samahu/) on 2020-08-12**:
@scpeters At one point, I tried omitting the  for a tiff height-map that had associated geo-reference information, gazebo loads the map with proper elevation (I measured that) but the desired_width & desired_height was not in line with the geo-reference information. The map had a size of 5mx5m but gazebo gave me 20mx20m. How do I report a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should be using the formula `max_elevation-min_elevation` which mean the z_scale value would `5.0-1.0=4.0.`

---

Originally posted by [lakshmi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28660/lakshmi/) with karma: 26 on 2020-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2020-08-07**:
yes, I believe this is the right way to compute the scale, which should have units of length